# Does ratcheting affect nesting structures and "frugal quatifiers"?

Tags: regex, raku, ratchet

In Perl 6 one can use the tilde operator for nesting structures.
Apparently ratcheting affects how the nesting structure works.

This case doesn't use ratcheting:

```
$ perl6 -e "say '{hello} aaa }' ~~ / '{' ~ '}' ( .+? ) /"
｢{hello}｣
 0 => ｢hello｣
```

while this does:

```
$ perl6 -e"say '{hello} aaa }' ~~ / :r '{' ~ '}' ( .+? ) /"
Nil
```

I can have the result I expect by changing the `.+?` pattern into the more specific `<-[}]> +`:

```
$ perl6 -e"say '{hello} aaa }' ~~ / :r '{' ~ '}' ( <-[}]> + ) /"
｢{hello}｣
 0 => ｢hello｣
```

but I don't know why the "frugal quantifier" doesn't work using ratcheting.
Any idea?

(using rakudo 2019.03.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`:ratchet` regex adverb](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/:ratchet) forbids the engine to backtrack into the quantified subpattern.

The first `/ :r '{' ~ '}' ( .+? ) /` pattern means that `.+?` pattern, after it matches any 1 or more chars, as few as possible, won't be re-tested, re-entered upon the subsequent pattern failure.

Here, in your `{hello} aaa }` example, after testing `{`, the `.+?` matches `h`, and then `}` fails to match `e`. Since no backtracking is allowed the match is failed and the next iteration starts: `h` is tested for `{`, and fails, etc.

The second regex with `<-[}]> +`  works because this matches any 1+ chars *other than `}`*, and that is the crucial difference from `.+?` that could match `}` and obligatorily consumed at least 1 char (due to `+`). Thus, it can't consume `}` and finds a match.

Comment: Since this is equivalent to the notion of *atomic group* in traditional NFA regexps, you may compare the corresponding pattern tests at regex101, see [pattern 1](https://regex101.com/r/aSwe8v/2/) and [pattern 2](https://regex101.com/r/aSwe8v/1/) demos. Click *regex debugger* to see matching in action.